# Cassandra tables are not auto generated in Spring Boot app

Tags: java, spring, cassandra

I am trying to create a `Spring Boot` CRUD application using `Cassandra`. I created a docker image and I already configured Cassandra, in `CassandraConfiguration` class but still is not creating my tables.

My `CassandraConfiguration.java` code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories
public class CassandraConfiguration extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

  @Value("${env.values.cassandra.keyspace.name}")
  private String keyspaceName;
  .......................................

  @Override
  protected String getKeyspaceName() {
    return keyspaceName;
  }

  @Override
  protected int getPort() {
    return contactPort;
  }
  @Override
  protected String getContactPoints() {
    return contactPoint;
  }
  @Override
  public SchemaAction getSchemaAction() {
    return SchemaAction.CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS;
  }
  @Override
  protected List<CreateKeyspaceSpecification> getKeyspaceCreations() {
    return List.of(
        CreateKeyspaceSpecification.createKeyspace(keyspaceName)
            .ifNotExists()
            .withSimpleReplication(3));
  }

  @Bean
  @Override
  public CqlSessionFactoryBean cassandraSession() {
    CqlSessionFactoryBean cassandraSession =
        super.cassandraSession(); // super session should be called only once
    cassandraSession.setUsername(username);
    cassandraSession.setPassword(password);
    return cassandraSession;
  }
}
```

My entity:

```
@Table
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id"})
@Getter
@Setter
public class Account {
  @PrimaryKey private String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
  private String username;
  private String email;
  private String name;
  private String password;
}
```

My `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

After I've done quick check of the code and configuration you posted, nothing was obvious to me as being incorrect.

My suggestion is to review the application logs looking specifically for errors and warnings from the Cassandra Java driver. Chances are the Cassandra cluster is unreachable from your application usually because of some networking issue.

You will need to verify that there is network connectivity between your application and the contact points + CQL port you've configured. Cheers!